# QT ButtonGroup and checkable PushButtons: how to connect toggled signal with int and bool?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have connected non-checkable push buttons from a ButtonGroup like this

```
connect(buttonGroupPtr, SIGNAL(buttonReleased(int)), this, SLOT(someFunction(int)));
```

now I want the Buttons to be checkabel and use the `toggled()` signal, which emits a `bool`. How do i combine the `int` that is emitted by the ButtonGroup and the `bool` that is emitted by the `toggled()` signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QButtonGroup` has `buttonToggled(int id, bool checked)` signal you can find [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/qbuttongroup.html#buttonToggled-1). So you can

```
connect(buttonGroupPtr, SIGNAL(buttonToggled(int, bool)), this, SLOT(someFunction(int, bool)));
```

Answer (score 0):

the toggle signal must be connected in another connect statement.

```
connect(buttonGroupPtr, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(mySlotToggled(bool)));
```